# How can I load/refresh divs inside parent div over the internet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Let's say that I have a parent div. And I want to insert/remove content or child divs periodically.
The web page resides on client side (it's a chrome extension).
Now, how can i achieve this?

Example

```
 <div class="parent">
 <div class="child1"></div>
 <div class="child2"></div>
 <div class="child3"></div>
 </div>
```

Is there any way that I can write the contents (like ) in a text file and have it injected inside the parent div the next time the user opens chrome and uses my extension.
Also If I wanted to remove the child1, I would simply remove the code for child1 in my text file and it will be updated on the client side.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can use ajax to pull data from a remote server.

Comment: @charlietfl How? I'm completely new to Ajax. Help me.

Comment: there are lots and lots of ajax tutorials online